# Sort a list of structures twice C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of structure with different datatypes like shown.

```
struct sample
{
    int nVal;
    string strVal;
    string strName;         
};
```

Now to sort that list accorsing to nVal, I used

```
bool sortList(const sample& a, const sample& b) // comparison function
{
    return a.nVal< b.nVal;
}
std::sort(sample.begin(), sample.end(), sortList);
```

Now my requirement is to sort the same list as per the string values in the structure but it should not affect the first sorting , that is with respect to int value. Please suggest me a way to achieve the sorthing of structure with out affecting previous sorting.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that if you require the order of equal elements to be preserved then use std::stable_sort instead of std::sort

Comment: When you say sort by "string values in the structure", does that include `strVal` and `strName` or just `strVal`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to sort first by `nVal`, but if elements have the same `nVal`, sort by the strings.

A simple to understand alternative to juanchopanza's answer that supports pre-C++11 compilers is:

```
bool sortList(const sample& a, const sample& b) // comparison function
{
    if (a.nVal == b.nVal)
    {
        if (a.strVal == b.a.strVal)
        {
            return a.strName < b.strName;
        }
        else
        {
            return a.strVal < b.strVal;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return a.nVal < b.nVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just sort according to both criteria in one pass. You can achieve this by implementing a *lexicographical comparison*, using `nVal` first, followed by `strVal`, and `strName`:

```
#include <tuple> // std::tie

bool sortList(const sample& a, const sample& b) // comparison function
{
    return std::tie(a.nVal, a.strVal, a.strName) < 
           std::tie(b.nVal, b.strVal, b.strName);
}
```

When used with sorting algorithms such as [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) or [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort), this will result in a sorting based on `nVal` first, then `strVal`, then `strName`. The use of `std::tie` is just a means to simplify the implementation of the lexicographical comparison, but you can do it by hand (this is both tedious and error-prone.)

**Note** If you want to maintain the original ordering of elements considered to be equivalent according to the comparison criteria, use `std::stable_sort`. Otherwise, use `std::sort`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I added links to `sort` and `stable_sort`. I was trying to figure out what exactly OP needs.

Comment: (Now it might also be worth mentioning that `stable_sort` doesn’t require you to compose your comparison functions.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph I must be missing something obvious, or reading the question differently, because I don't get that point.